# How to serve static and uploaded content in Java Spring Boot MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try with following process to serve static content but have no luck.

I have written the below code in my application.properties:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/public/
```

where public is the directory of my static and uploaded content, like user profile and others.

but it's giving me a 404 error when I access the file like:

```
http://localhost:8082/public/uploads/file/a.png
```

I have also tried with:

```
http://localhost:8082/uploads/file/a.png
```

but it does not working either.

Comment: dont put uploaded content inside your jar

Comment: can you please explore the solution , i did not get  dont put uploaded content inside your jar

Comment: Mine was just a suggestion about what you wrote, not a solution. Anyway, try with  http://localhost:8082/file/a.png

Answer (score 0):

If you have **server.servlet.context-path** (or server.servlet.contextPath, it's the same) set in your application.properties, you need to have this part in the URL, for example:

server.servlet.context-path=/foo

then you should visit http://localhost:8082/foo/uploads/file/a.png

Comment: i have already  set  context path in  my application

server.servlet.contextPath=/api

i try with that but i am getting {"success":false,"error":"You don't have permission to perform this action."}
response
and there is one class file of web security is

Comment: @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  if (docsEnabled) {
   web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
     .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").antMatchers("/configuration/**").antMatchers("/webjars/**")
     .antMatchers("/public");
  }
 }

Comment: @MSwapnil Yes, it's the web security, you need to add this `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**");` just below the `if (docsEnabled) { ... }` block.

Comment: @MSwapnil But you need to know, simply adding `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**");`    is just to demonstrate how to solve the problem, definitely not production-ready, it would allow anyone to visit all `/api/**`, I believe you have your own logic to determine if a user should be allowed to visit the static content, you might want to take a look at this article , it would be helpful : [Spring Security – Roles and Privileges](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't have other configuration parameters set, spring boot should serve static resources under /

So if your static resources are under a folder called `public/file` you'll find that at the url  `localhost:8082/file/a.png`

If you have `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` parameter set spring boot should serve static resources at that path

In the case of spring.mvc.static-path-pattern = files (for example) it will serve them at `http://localhost:8082/files/file/a.png`

Here's a good article explaining all :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources